# How to add headers to HTTP response within ClientErrorException?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jetty, jax-rs, java-ee-7

I have a custom `ClientErrorException` and I want to add some specific headers to the response when this exception is thrown.

For example, I can specify status of the response in the constructor:

```
public ClientErrorException(String message, Response.Status status) {
...
}
```

But how to specify headers? What the proper way to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an [ExceptionMapper](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/ext/ExceptionMapper.html) for jax-rs to return a custom response when an exception is thrown.

There is a nice example in [here](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/ae/twbs_jaxrs_defresource_exception_mapper.html)